# Paypal with error code 10413

Tags: php, paypal

These are the following data passed to the paypal express checkout. But it returns an error with code 10413.

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=232.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=232.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_n_HANDLINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWNOTE=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Purple & Pink Pumpkin Tutu Dress - Infant, Toddler & Girls&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Purple & Pink Pumpkin Tutu Dress - Infant, Toddler & Girls&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=232.00&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
```

I wasn't able to find the issue with the url.

Comment: Did you Google the error message? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/ - *"Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details - The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts. - If you receive this error, be sure the total of the payment detail item parameters, such as ItemTotal, HandlingTotal, TaxTotal, and so forth add up to the order total."*

Comment: Probably the ampersands `&` in your descriptions `Purple & Pink Pumpkin Tutu Dress` etc. causing the problem and/or something in your script/code. Try and use the word `and` instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thank You. That was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the question: (comment to answer) with a few additional notes.

It's probably the ampersands `&` in your descriptions `Purple & Pink Pumpkin Tutu Dress` etc. causing the problem.

Try and use the word `and` instead.

PayPal is interpreting the ampersands as an additional expression.

You probably could get away and use `&amp;` instead if you really want the ampersands to appear as `&` in the descriptions.

Comment: When I create a url with &amp; the same issue happens:PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=232.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=232.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_n_HANDLINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-0.00&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWNOTE=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Purple &amp; Pink Pumpkin Tutu Dress - Infant, Toddler &amp; Girls&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Purple &amp; Pink Pumpkin Tutu Dress - Infant, Toddler &amp; Girls&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=232.00&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1

Comment: @Nishaharidas I guess you can't use `&amp;` then, it must be `and`.

Comment: You accepted my answer and now you changed your mind, why? @Nishaharidas

Comment: I got error while using the &amp;. Now I used the urlencode and its working perfectly.